# Create a sequence of intervals in R

Tags: r, sequence, intervals

I have a piece of following code but the annoying thing is that I don't know how to automatically generate sequence of `intervals` (where the second value of the last one is the first of the next one). There must be a better way to do it than manually! Help will be much appreciated.

```
intervals <- list(c(0,0.1),
                  c(0.1,0.2), 
                  c(0.2,0.3),
                  c(0.3,0.4),
                  c(0.4,0.5),
                  c(0.5,0.6),
                  c(0.6,0.7),
                  c(0.7,0.8),
                  c(0.8,0.9),
                  c(0.9,1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do with `Map`.  Create a sequence from 0 to 1 `by` 0.1, then use `Map` to concatenate the elements in 's1' by removing the last and first value

```
s1 <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)
Map(c, s1[-length(s1)], s1[-1])
```